# Googleapiclient is not disconnecting

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, google-signin

Hi I am providing my code snippet for logging out of google account. On clicking 'SignOut' button I am calling this logout function. I was able to sign in with google account successfully. Using the below code I am able to logout of Google account but need to click on Signout button many times for getting logged out. I think mGoogleApiClient is taking too long time for getting connected and hence to enter mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() condition.

Can somebody help me to get logged out of google account on single click of SignOut button?

```
public void logout(String st)
{`enter code here`
   mGoogleApiClient.connect();
   if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()||mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) 
   {
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) 
        {
            mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            System.err.println("LOG OUT ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ SUCESS");
            refreshpage();
        }
    }
}

public void refreshpage()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use like this

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                // ...
            }
        });
```

Comment: Still the same... After 5 or 6 clicks its getting disconnected :(

Comment: answer updated, by using this you can show some (progress bar) / (disable button)

Comment: For the above code also when I tried without having if condition check of if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) it was throwing mGoogleApiClient is not yet connected error. But when I added the check again its behaving the same. Need to have 5-6 clicks to get it logged out. I think its taking some time to change mGoogleApiClient's status from connecting to connected

Comment: dear its a async call it should take but but the thing is you have to show some progress bar or something till you get some result in callback